# "Widgets" menu doesn't appear

Tags: menus, widgets

I'm developing a WordPress theme, which works great on my localhost and one of my live servers, but on my other live server the Widgets menu (from Appearance) doesn't appear. And yes, all 3 servers have the same 3.6.1 WordPress version, and the theme files are the same. Any idea what could cause this?

Here's the area of `functions.php` that registers the widget areas:

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'RLTheme - Footer Left',
    'id'   => 'rltheme_footer_left',
    'description'   => 'The left area of the footer.',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget'  => '',
    'before_title'  => '<h3>',
    'after_title'   => '<span></span></h3>'
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'RLTheme - Footer Center',
    'id'   => 'rltheme_footer_center',
    'description'   => 'The center area of the footer.',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget'  => '',
    'before_title'  => '<h3>',
    'after_title'   => '<span></span></h3>'
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'RLTheme - Footer Right',
    'id'   => 'rltheme_footer_right',
    'description'   => 'The right area of the footer.',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget'  => '',
    'before_title'  => '<h3>',
    'after_title'   => '<span></span></h3>'
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'RLTheme - Sidebar Left',
    'id'   => 'rltheme_sidebar_left',
    'description'   => 'The right sidebar area.',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar_area">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3>',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>'
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'RLTheme - Sidebar Right',
    'id'   => 'rltheme_sidebar_right',
    'description'   => 'The left sidebar area.',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar_area">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3>',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>'
));
}
```

P.S. If I switch from my theme to the default one (on that live server where I can't see the "Widgets" menu when I activate my theme) I can see the "Widgets" menu, so the WordPress installation there doesn't appear to be broken.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: Also, your code works for me as it does on a couple of your servers :)  What is _different_ about the server where this doesn't work? PHP version? OS? What?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.17 -> (my live server; "Widgets" menu doesn't appear)
PHP Version 5.3.8 -> (my localhost; everything works fine here)
PHP Version 5.4.17 -> (my other live server; everything works fine here)

The localhost server is installed on Win 7 and the other two live servers are installed on CentOS. I've set wp_debug to true on all of them and no errors appear.

Answer (score 1):

Another difference between those servers which was actually the problem was that the live server where the issue occurred had been installed via fantastico. After manually reinstalling it, everything was fine.